# Why did the files in "Changes not staged for commit" disappear after git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

While using Git, I did the following steps:

1. Made changes to a file, such as `a.txt`.
2. Used *git add a.txt* to stage it.
3. Made additional changes to `a.txt`

At this point, running git status shows that there is an entry for `a.txt` in both *"Changes to be committed"* and *"Changes not staged for commit."*

4. Executed `git commit -m "..." a.txt`.

Now you notice that a.txt has disappeared from both "Changes to be committed" and "Changes not staged for commit."

**Why did this happen?**

It's normal for `a.txt` to disappear from the Staged area after the `git commit`, but why did it also disappear from "Changes not staged for commit"?

I tried `git show HEAD:a.txt` - the result is the same as the last version.

Comment: If you can follow this process yourself, you can find this problem。。。

Comment: You Executed   git commit -m "..."      I Executed  git commit -m "..."  a.txt  That's different

Comment: Well, the whole point of doing that is to `a.txt` to the commit. "The content to be committed can be specified in several ways: [...] by listing files as arguments to the commit command [...]"

Comment: yes,, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those changes "disappeared" because you committed them.

Per the [git-commit docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) (emphasis mine),

> The content to be committed can be specified in several ways:
> ...
> 3. by listing files as arguments to the commit command (without --interactive or --patch switch), in which case the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead **record the current content of the listed files** (which must already be known to Git);

You said you ran `git commit -m "..." a.txt`. This commits the current state of `a.txt`, whether you had staged changes or not. That also explains why `git show HEAD:a.txt` matches the current state of that file - because you committed the current state of that file - and why `a.txt` no longer shows up in either "changes to be committed" or "changes not yet staged for commit" - because every change in that file has already been committed.

Comment: Perfect answer! thank u!